# Reducir código con lombok en proyecto de Java con Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, lombok

¿Cómo podría reducir código para los métodos *getter* y *setter* de los siguientes atributos?

Por la documentación, con **Lombok** podría pero no sé cómo, asumiendo que ya he incluido la dependencia en mi proyecto *maven* en el *pom.xml*

Aunque parte lo genera la IDE querría tener mejor organizado el código y mas limpio.

Desde la web  https://projectlombok.org/ de la librería no he visto demasiada información sobre ello, pero por lo que indica es la librería correcta.

```
// Define una clase para representar un objeto de transferencia de datos (DTO) para usuarios
package com.draftdesignweb.microservicios.model;

public class UserDTO {
    
    // Atributos de la clase para almacenar información del usuario
    private Integer id;         // Identificador del usuario
    private String name;        // Nombre del usuario
    private String lastname;    // Apellido del usuario
    private int edad;           // Edad del usuario

    // Métodos getter y setter para acceder y modificar los atributos privados

    // Getter para obtener el identificador del usuario
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Setter para establecer el identificador del usuario
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Getter para obtener el nombre del usuario
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // Setter para establecer el nombre del usuario
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getter para obtener el apellido del usuario
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    // Setter para establecer el apellido del usuario
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    // Getter para obtener la edad del usuario
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    // Setter para establecer la edad del usuario
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    // Fin de la clase UserDTO
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solucion a esta duda se encuentra en https://projectlombok.org/features/Data
Aqui muestra la anotacion @Data la cual segun la web mencionada anteriormente especifica que:

> All together now: A shortcut for @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter on all fields, @Setter on all non-final fields, and @RequiredArgsConstructor!

El codigo usando esto debe ser algo como:

```java
// Define una clase para representar un objeto de transferencia de datos (DTO) para usuarios
package com.draftdesignweb.microservicios.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class UserDTO {
    private Integer id;     
    private String name;        
    private String lastname;    
    private int edad;         
    
}
```

Recuerda que para que lombok funcione correctamente necesitas agregar el plugin a tu IDE.

---

Fuera de esto te recomiendo que mires la forma correcta para documentar tu codigo en JAVA, si bien usar comentarios no esta mal, puedes mejorarlo usando JavaDocs

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Danild, me fue de gran ayuda!

Comment: pudes pone otras anotaciones como  noargsconstructor y allconstructor para constructor sin parametros y con